# MySQL aggregate function with GROUP BY to avoid NULL's overwriting desired field value

Tags: mysql, sql

With the following query I am only get a single day of the week with dates in it, while all other days for each lesson_number are producing NULL.

```
SELECT
    lesson_number,
    CASE WHEN dayofweek = 0 THEN lesson_date END AS 'MONDAY',
    CASE WHEN dayofweek = 1 THEN lesson_date END AS 'TUESDAY',
    CASE WHEN dayofweek = 2 THEN lesson_date END AS 'WEDNESDAY',
    CASE WHEN dayofweek = 3 THEN lesson_date END AS 'THURSDAY',
    CASE WHEN dayofweek = 4 THEN lesson_date END AS 'FRIDAY',
    CASE WHEN dayofweek = 5 THEN lesson_date END AS 'SATURDAY',
    CASE WHEN dayofweek = 6 THEN lesson_date END AS 'SUNDAY'
FROM calendar_dates
GROUP BY lesson_number;
```

Produces something like:

```
    MON    TUE    WED    THU    FRI    SAT    SUN
1   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-09-07
2   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-09-14
3   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-09-21
4   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-09-28
5   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-10-xx
6   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-10-xx
7   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-10-xx
8   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-10-xx
```

Without using `GROUP BY` it returns something like this:

```
       MON       TUE    WED    THU    FRI    SAT    SUN
1      NULL      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-09-07
2      NULL      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-09-14
3      NULL      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-09-21
4      NULL      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-09-28
5      NULL      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-10-xx
6      NULL      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-10-xx
7      NULL      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-10-xx
8      NULL      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   2014-10-xx
1   2014-09-07   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
2   2014-09-07   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
3   2014-09-07   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
4   2014-09-07   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
5   2014-09-07   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
6   2014-09-07   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
7   2014-09-07   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
8   2014-09-07   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
```

Where there is 8 results for each day.

I want to somehow "coalesce" the dates for each day of the week to avoid NULL values. I have tried both the `COALESCE` and `GROUP_CONCAT` functions, but they don't seem meant for this. Is there some sort of way to `"GROUP_COALESCE"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just aggregate your results using `MAX`:

```
SELECT
    lesson_number,
    MAX(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 0 THEN lesson_date END) AS 'MONDAY',
    MAX(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 1 THEN lesson_date END) AS 'TUESDAY',
    MAX(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 2 THEN lesson_date END) AS 'WEDNESDAY',
    MAX(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 3 THEN lesson_date END) AS 'THURSDAY',
    MAX(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 4 THEN lesson_date END) AS 'FRIDAY',
    MAX(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 5 THEN lesson_date END) AS 'SATURDAY',
    MAX(CASE WHEN dayofweek = 6 THEN lesson_date END) AS 'SUNDAY'
FROM calendar_dates
GROUP BY lesson_number;
```

Comment: That's awesome. I knew it would be simple. I tried using MAX(lesson_date) after each THEN clause, which didn't work. And also MAX before CASE, but I didn't know where to close the function so ended up with syntax errors. Thanks a bunch!!